# Background cover + parallax

Tags: jquery, css, fixed, parallax, cover

i'm making full page with fixed background with cover.

When i add parallax - animation looks great, but it lagging so much, i don't know why.
I have good PC so it's not this problem, i made others parallax before and that's not lagging.

It is any solution?

BG

```
section#section-1{
background:url("../img/section-1-bg.jpg")50% 0px no-repeat fixed;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
-ms-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
}
```

Parallax plugin: jQuery Parallax
Version 1.1.3

Comment: Maybe you'll find your answer in [this article](http://kristerkari.github.io/adventures-in-webkit-land/blog/2013/08/30/fixing-a-parallax-scrolling-website-to-run-in-60-fps/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the background-size property. When you remove it, it should run smooth.

There is a jQuery plugin that stretches background images and uses less ressources than css background-size.
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/